# Just don't cross the streams

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Feels stupid, but could anyone explain to me in plan English, the real meaning or the funny bit of this comment: "Just don't cross the streams and you will be alight" from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224563/151832)

My only guess is: could that because the OP mentioned "close the stream", and the commenter is suggesting I didn't get it wrong for cross the stream (as a classic scene in the film)??

Comment: It's a reference to a line from the movie Ghostbusters.  A plot point in the movie is that one character tells the others, "Don't cross the streams.  It would be bad."  Think of it as a meme, though an old one that predates internet culture.

Comment: The joke isn't really meaningful, besides the fact that "don't cross the streams" somewhat resembles the sentence "you have to close the streams."  He probably just assumed you, (or other people) would know the reference and find it amusing, though not really having anything to do with the question.

Comment: @Kai, I see... got it!

Comment: @Kai I'd like to recommend you to post your comments as an answer. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a reference to a line from the movie Ghostbusters. A plot point in the movie is that one character tells the others, "Don't cross the streams. It would be bad." Think of it as a meme, though an old one that predates internet culture.

The joke isn't really meaningful, besides the fact that "don't cross the streams" somewhat resembles the sentence "you have to close the streams." He probably just assumed you, (or other people) would know the reference and find it amusing, though not really having anything to do with the question.